# Project Timeline in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

My users are wanting to be able to see the status of various rooms (Y axis) across dates (X axis) in a project timeline format.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

I was hoping to maybe utilize the bar chart widget, but it looks like that requires the fields to be numerical (dates won't work).

Like I said, I realize it is a long shot, but I figured I would try.

Answer (score 3):

I was using this library https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/ to implement scheduler in App Maker project. But it can be switched to bar timeline widget. Here is an example: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/06_timeline/02_lines.html

To add the widget to your project, open project settings, find **External resources** and add to 
**JavaScript URLs**:

```html
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/codebase/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_timeline.js
//cdn.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/edge/dhtmlxscheduler.js
```

Also you need to add library styles to **CSS URLs**:

```html
//cdn.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/edge/dhtmlxscheduler.css
```

Now we can init this widget in a project. Add Html widget to your page. For example it has Projects datasource. Check allowUnsafeHtml property and put html code into it:

```html
<div id="schedulerContainer" tabindex="0" aria-label="events calendar" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:960px; height:555px;">
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dhx_cal_header">Timeline is not loaded</div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
</div>
```

And add widget initialization to onDataLoad event of the Html widget:

```js
initTimeline(widget);
```

Now let's create client script and implementation of function **initTimeline**:

```js
function initTimeline(widget) {
  const datasource = widget.datasource;

  // shceduler is a global variable
  scheduler.locale.labels.timeline_tab = "Timeline";
  scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom = "Section";
  scheduler.config.details_on_create = true;
  scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick = true;
  scheduler.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";

  //===============
  //Configuration
  //===============

  // sections can fetched from datasource items
  var sections = [{
      key: 1,
      label: "James Smith"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      label: "John Williams"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      label: "David Miller"
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      label: "Linda Brown"
    }
  ];

  scheduler.createTimelineView({
    name: "timeline",
    x_unit: "minute",
    x_date: "%H:%i",
    x_step: 30,
    x_size: 24,
    x_start: 16,
    x_length: 48,
    y_unit: sections,
    y_property: "section_id",
    render: "bar"
  });

  //===============
  //Data loading
  //===============
  scheduler.config.lightbox.sections = [{
      name: "description",
      height: 130,
      map_to: "text",
      type: "textarea",
      focus: true
    },
    {
      name: "custom",
      height: 23,
      type: "select",
      options: sections,
      map_to: "section_id"
    },
    {
      name: "time",
      height: 72,
      type: "time",
      map_to: "auto"
    }
  ];

  scheduler.init('schedulerContainer', new Date(2017, 5, 30), "timeline");

  /*
    this data also can be fetched from datasource and parsed 
    to proper format using code like this:
  
    const data = datasource.items.map((item) => {
      return {
        start_date: item.start_date,
        end_date: item.end_date,
        text: item.name,
        section_id: item.category_id
      };  
    });
    
  */

  scheduler.parse([{
      start_date: "2017-06-30 09:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 12:00",
      text: "Task A-12458",
      section_id: 1
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 10:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 16:00",
      text: "Task A-89411",
      section_id: 1
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 10:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 14:00",
      text: "Task A-64168",
      section_id: 1
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 16:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 17:00",
      text: "Task A-46598",
      section_id: 1
    },

    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 12:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 20:00",
      text: "Task B-48865",
      section_id: 2
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 14:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 16:00",
      text: "Task B-44864",
      section_id: 2
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 16:30",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 18:00",
      text: "Task B-46558",
      section_id: 2
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 18:30",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 20:00",
      text: "Task B-45564",
      section_id: 2
    },

    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 08:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 12:00",
      text: "Task C-32421",
      section_id: 3
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 14:30",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 16:45",
      text: "Task C-14244",
      section_id: 3
    },

    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 09:20",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 12:20",
      text: "Task D-52688",
      section_id: 4
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 11:40",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 16:30",
      text: "Task D-46588",
      section_id: 4
    },
    {
      start_date: "2017-06-30 12:00",
      end_date: "2017-06-30 18:00",
      text: "Task D-12458",
      section_id: 4
    }
  ], "json");
}
```

This answer is a general guide how to add this widget. But it may contain errors, so I'd advise you to take a look at the [widget documentation](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/how_to_start.html) as well

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no native timeline chart support in App Maker. I would suggest trying to find a JS library that can draw a timeline and use that in your App Maker application. The Google visualization library has a timeline chart I believe and the library is included by default in App Maker applications.

Comment: When adding a JS library, what syntax am I looking for the for Script ID? Something like this, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"? Because that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Something like: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` and it definitely works.

Comment: So I am going under" App Settings" for my app, then clicking "Add Library" under the "Apps Script Libraries" section. Then I pasted the link from Tony (above) into the Script ID field and after a moment get the error: "No script found, please enter a valid script ID". What am I doing wrong? (Thank you for the help!)

Comment: For a plain JS script, you want to add a JS URL in the settings page. The "Add Library" is for adding Apps Script libraries.